# Trying to change point style -> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: openlayers, javascript

I'm trying to change the style of some points of a GeoJSON file loaded in OpenLayers and I getting this error:

`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I want to modify the point style related to a GRID_CODE value, located inside the file. I can access the value and iterate the whole array of values with no problem, the error only shows when I try to modify the feature. I tried to change only the point color, but the same error happens.

My code:

```
var myVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource ({
    format: new GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:31982'}),
    url: '/geojson/flowdirection.geojson'
  }),
  zIndex: 55
});

// Change style to a arrow image, relative to the GRID_CODE
myVectorLayer .getSource().on('change', function(evt){
  var newsource = evt.target;
  var myFeatures = newsource.getFeatures();

  if (newsource.getState() === 'ready') {
    var numFeatures = newsource.getFeatures().length;
    for (var i=0; i < numFeatures; i++) {
      // Get the grid code
      var gridCode = myFeatures[i].get("GRID_CODE");
      // Change the point style to an arrow image
      if (gridCode == 1) {
        myFeatures[i].setStyle(new Style({
          image: new Icon({
            src: 'img/arrow.png'
          })
        }))
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Try defining icon style `iconStyle = new Style({ ...` only once outside loop and then apply this style to features: `myFeatures[i].setStyle(iconStyle)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be more efficient to use a style function

```
var style1 = new Style({
  image: new Icon({
    src: 'img/arrow.png'
  })
});
....

var myVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource ({
    format: new GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:31982'}),
    url: '/geojson/flowdirection.geojson'
  }),
  style: function(feature){
      var gridCode = feature.get("GRID_CODE");
      // Change the point style to a arrow image
      if (gridCode == 1) {
        return style1;
      } else {
        ....
      }
  },
  zIndex: 55
});
```

Comment: Thanks again Mike, it worked! I hope this helps somebody else in the future.